# Codeigniter insert html line in php form

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I use codeigniter to show registration form like in the code below and I just want to add a line "By clicking Register, you agree to our Terms" but the syntax of that line is not correct. Could you please help me.

```
<?php 
echo form_open();
              blablabla
echo form_input($data);
echo ("By clicking Register, you agree to our <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>terms/" target="_blank">Privacy  Terms</a>");
echo form_submit('submit','Register');
echo form_close(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need the brackets after echo. Why not like this:

```
<?= form_open();?>
//Your html stuff
<?=form_submit();?>
<?= form_close();?>
```

Comment: FYI:  CodeIgniter specifically recommends against using PHP shorthand.  See:  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html#short_open_tags

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
 <?php     
 echo form_open();    
 echo form_input($data);    
 echo "By clicking Register, you agree to our <a href='".base_url()."terms/'     
 target='_blank'>Privacy  Terms</a>";   
 echo form_submit('submit','Register');    
 echo form_close();     
 ?>
```